# I am trying to get the file metadata from sharepoint via mule

Tags: mule

Anyone having the sample demo/ example "To Get File Metadata sharepoint" Mule.

Any resource/reference link as well would be appreciated..

Thanx

Comment: Can you provide more context? What is that example you are talking about?

Comment: i want to retrieve the file metadata from sharepoint under "Shared Documents" using MULE